How to handle number of queries that need to be run hourly
I have a usecase where my workers have run about ~100 queries at an hourly cadence. I don't want to have 100 individual lambdas run each of them separately as the count of queues may increase in the future.
I want to run them on a ECS, for workers to pick those queries and run with max parallelism of 5. My question is what's the best way to track the query execution. All the metadata of query(query name, path,..) are stored in a dynamo table.
Ideally, I am looking to post those entries into a SQS Queue every hour i.e. on schedule the SQS is populated with 100 entries for the queries that are run on Aurora Postgres. Workers on ECS constantly poll the queue to get the query metadata, run it and delete the message from the Queue. Workers scale down once the SQS is empty.
I want to use scheduled Lambda to populate the Queue and help with spinning up EKS. Am I complicating the design here.


FWIW, EKS/Fargate and ECS/Fargate are very different things.  but I really don't see the logic behind bringing ECS into the equation.  You're clearly already comfortable with lambda.  It integrates with SQS beautifully and can do batching with partial failure responses and max concurrency limitations.  SQS Lambda seems like a slam dunk here.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-sqs-configure.html explains how most of your details become event mapping configuration from sqs to lambda.

@erik258 it is a busy db with a hue volume. I am afraid the queries will hither 15 min ceiling with lambda functions. That's the reason for a different compute.

As mentioned, ECS and EKS are very different, and you mention both. Which one are you using? I think this design with ECS would be fine.

got it, I am new to the specifics. Will work on the ECS/EKS difference and update the notes. Thanks for the pointers!

Yep, lambda not right if queries longer than 15 minutes.  Next simplest is ECS/Fargate. Scale the service down to 0 on queue depth, up to 5, and then run a naive single threaded queue worker on each task.  Pro tip, set your long poll wait time as high as acceptable to minimize costs and make sure to scale to zero when the queues are empty.

yup, scaling up and down the cluster based on queue size and cluster utilization.  Thanks!

To make it better, you can remove the use of ECS and use aws Batch instead, and aws batch will create an ECS in the background whenever it gets triggered and afterwards it will be automatically cleaned. Using AWS Batch can simplify your setup even further, especially if you're looking to reduce the operational overhead of managing ECS tasks. And you can configure it also to use spot instances. Configure AWS Batch to limit the max parallelism to 5 (or any desired number). And Jobs automatically scale up and down based on the queue size.
